# Redirect some of the languages on a multi-language site

Tags: redirect, plugin-wpml

I have a site that uses WPML to display three languages.

- EN - www.domain.com
- FR - www.domain.com/fr/
- ES - www.domain.com/es/

I want to set up redirects so that all of the EN and FR pages (home and inner pages) are redirected (on a page-by-page basis) to pages on a different domain. However, a user that visits the home page with their browser language set to ES would be redirected to www.domain.com/es/.

I can use the Redirection [plugin](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) for the EN and FR redirects but by doing so, all users (including those with a browser language set to ES) are automatically redirected to the new domain. In other words, the ES redirect doesn't work since it's second in the redirect queue.

What are my options?